# Is it possible to add 2 distinct Content-Disposition headers in the following way

Tags: c#, content-disposition, response.addheader

```cs
 oResponse.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName_DBText, Encoding.UTF8).Replace("+", "%20"));
 oResponse.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName_DBText, Encoding.UTF8).Replace("+", "%20"));
```

The above was causing me an issue in Chrome only. No issue in IE or Firefox.
Removal of the 2nd AddHeader (adding the inline directive), resolved the issue.
I was under the impression that adding both was fine and the browser would work out what to do.
Anyone have a definitive answer on this?

Answer (score 2):

a) no, you can't have multiple ones.

b) the syntax for the second one is invalid; "inline" doesn't take a parameter.

c) "inline" and "attachment" are contradictory; what are you trying to achieve?

(the spec is RFC 6266, btw)

Comment: I was mistaken in thinking you could specify the filename for downloaded files rendered in the browser and those where the user is prompted to open/save/save as, separately.
I didn't realise it was either/or.

Comment: Re. point A) we had a program allowing a user to click a link to view an attachment that had been uploaded. The prompt was asking them to save/save as/open  a file whose name was made up of the aspx page and the uploaded file extension, so if the page was mypage.aspx & the file was .xls, it prompted them for mypage.xls, which was obv wrong. We wanted to display the real filename
So using the content-disposition tag was the way to go, but I mistakenly thought I had to cater for the diff filetypes by using attachment AND inline.

Comment: Re. point b), as an example, would the following be correct if using inline -

response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=myfile.xls");

Answer (score 0):

Solution was very straightforward:
Simply removed the following line of code -

```cs
oResponse.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fileName_DBText, Encoding.UTF8).Replace("+", "%20"));
```

As @Julian Reschike stated, you cannot have multiple content-disposition headers, which I wasn't aware of. In any case, the syntax of the above line was incorrect as I had it.
Line removed and everything back to how it should be.